# Number of Divisors of most numbers

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, divisor-counting-function

In the book A Comprehensive Course in Number Theory by Alan Baker. The author mentions that even though the average order of $\tau(n)$ is $\log n$, almost all numbers have about $(\log n)^{\log 2}$ divisors.

$\tau(n)$=number of divisors of n.

I was wondering how one would prove this result. If anyone has any ideas it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$
\sum_{n\le x}\tau(n)\sim \sum_{n\le x}\log(n),
$$
so that the average value of $\tau(n)$ is indeed $\log(n)$, but from Hardy and Ramanujan we know, since $2^{\omega(n)}\le \tau(n)\le 2­^{\Omega(n)}$, that for most numbers $n$, 
$$
\tau(n)=\log(n)^{\log(2)+o(1)},
$$
where $\log (2)$ is around $0.693$. The normal value of $\omega (n)$ resp. $\Omega(n)$ is $\log(\log(n))$, by Hardy and Ramanujan.

Comment: can you please tell what are $\omega(n),\Omega(n)$

Comment: $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, and $\Omega(n)$ its multiplicities, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function),